# Vuetify & Vue3 - v-list-item "to" property is not creating a link

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I've got a new Vue3 project and have the following in the vuetify nav drawer:

```
      <v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item to='/' :title="$t('app.home')"></v-list-item>
          <v-list-item to='/new' :title="$t('app.new')"></v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
```

For some reason, these are not links even though v-list-item has a `to` prop that implictily sets the `link` property to true.

If I add a `router-link` it works but breaks the style (verifying that my router configuration is right).

Why is my "to" prop not working here? This is just modifying the default templates that get generated when creating a new vue3 project and adding vuetify....

Comment: The template code (minus i18n strings) works fine in a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7i9jjt?file=src/App.vue).  We'll need more code to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] showcasing the bug. Use codesandbox, stackblitz or similar.